# Spring: How can you declare name/value pairs outside a Map?

Tags: java, spring

I have a need to set a collection of name/value pairs inside my application - representing effectively a many-to-many map (i.e. keys can have multiple values and vice-versa), so Hashtable and Hashmap don't really work for me.

I'd like to be able to declare these via Spring in a format similar to `<props>`, but of course that won't work directly because Properties extends Hashtable itself.

IE, I want to be able to declare something like this:

```
<entry>
   <key><value>KeyOne</value></key>
   <value>ValueOne</value>
</entry>
<entry>
   <key><value>KeyOne</value></key>
   <value>ValueTwo</value>
</entry>
```

inside a property - but can't use `<map>, <props>`, and can't see a good way to use `<set>` or `<list>`. Any bright ideas?

I don't necessarily need a map-like syntax as in the above; but have that for now as I've initially implemented this code with a HashMap as the actual data structure being set by Spring. After discovering my 1-1 map is really a 1-many or even many-many, here I am.

Thanks.

Comment: So how will you find the correct value if key KeyOne can have two values?  What are you trying to do?  Which version of the JDK are you using (will generics be a problem)?

Comment: In my code on the other end, I'll probably just iterate through the collection and look at each item in there individually (so I'd be more than OK with a set or list, if there were a way to define the elements in something like the syntax above).

IE, I don't want a solution which requires me to define each element in the collection as a separate bean.

Comment: oh, and each 'item' in the magical world in my head where this worked out of the box would be a NameValuePair, except that doesn't exist in base Java, but you get the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about setting your collection entries as simple strings and decoding the key and value?

```
@Required
public void setData(String[] data) {
    // split each data element into key and value at the comma
}

<property name="data">
    <list>
        <value>key,value</value>
        <value>key,value</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

This is doing more work but gets you compact XML.

Comment: It's trivial and simple, and good enough - I like it. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Oh, and commas aren't a problem here; I'm actually using this data to set up a reflection scheme where I set field X of an object based on the value in field Y of another object - so commas obviously aren't valid in the strings themselves.